# AAD groups and MS teams sync is too slow

Tags: synchronization, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I created a team via my MS Teams client, which automatically created an Office365 group in my Azure AD. It also added me as the owner of the group.

Now I want to add more members to the group. I can do this in several ways:

- Add members directly to the team via MS teams client.
- Add users to office 365 group via Azure AD
- Add users to office 365 group via Microsoft 365 admin center
- Add users to office 365 group via Graph API
- Add users via Exchange Online PowerShell

When I use the first method, the members list in Teams is updated immediately.

But Teams doesn't reflect the changes immediately if I use any of these methods. The Microsoft documentation says that it may take up to 2 hours.

> If you DO add or remove team members outside of the Teams client (by
>   using the Microsoft 365 admin center, Azure AD, or Exchange Online
>   PowerShell), it can take up to two hours for changes to be reflected
>   in Teams.

But the sync process is much slower than this. In my case, it was more than 24 hrs.

Is there a solution to reduce this delay? Something like:

- A script to sync the Teams and office 365 group.
- Any other method that doesn't have this delay

Comment: If it's taking more than two hours, I recommend opening a support case. Be sure to have the details ready for: how and exactly when (record the time) you added the member using one of the other methods, and how and exactly when you checked if the change was recorded in Teams (take screenshots and record the exact time).

Comment: @Philippe Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to do manual sync? I mean writing our own sync-task or script?

Comment: Can I use tools like AADsync, DirSync or AzureAD connect or do a Start-ADSyncSyncCycle via ADSyncScheduler?

Comment: No, Azure AD Connect is for syncing to Azure AD, it's not for the internal sync between Azure AD and SharePoint Online and Exchange Online. I suggest opening a support case, you shouldn't be seeing delays that long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance issues like this a support case is probably your best option, like Philippe said. If you send me an email at AzCommunity@microsoft.com and include your Azure subscription ID, I can open a free case for you.

You can also leave product feedback in [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/).

There are some troubleshooting documents that suggest that you can click the retry button to get past the delays. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/known-issues

Comment: Been a year and we have started seeing this issue now. Removed Guest user from Graph API (both V1, BETA) , guest user still has access to TEAMS and gets removed almost after 2 days. Access from corresponding sharepoint site gets removed immediately

Comment: This isn't an answer.